# How to fetch data in json format from realtime-database (Firebase)?

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make a search functionality in my app which basically filter the json data (for eg. **product list**) according to the query of user(like any product name) and shows the nearest results. I have succesfully implemented this search bar and logic of filtering but it is working on the local json data of my **product list** I have in my app. What I want is to fetch the json data from Network call (http call) and then filter it .
But I have the data in my realtime-database and I do not know how to retrieve them as in json format. I could setup the cloud functions(node js) to return the json data to the client but I am not sure about what should be the logic in the cloud functions to connect it to realtime-database and return the response

**My data in Firebase**:
[image]

Now how can I fetch this data from my app through the cloud functions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure about what should be the logic in the cloud functions to
> connect it to realtime-database and return the response. .... how can
> I fetch this data from my app through the cloud functions ?

I understand that you want to use an [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) as a REST API endpoint (You write "What I want is to fetch the json data from Network call (http call)").

You can write a Cloud Function along the following lines:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.getRTDBData = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  
    const rtdbRootRef = admin.database().ref();

    const noticesDataSnapshot = await rtdbRootRef.child('notices').get();

    res.status(200).send(noticesDataSnapshot.val());   

});
```

When calling this HTTPS Cloud Function with an http call you will get the entire `notices`RTDB node. If necessary, it's up to you to adapt the RTDB query, for example by filtering data, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data).

In addition, I would suggest you watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&list) for more info on how to deal with errors in your HTTPS Cloud Function.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Is that response would be json data ?

Comment: Yes you will receive it as JSON.

Comment: Ok, I guess this is the answer of my question. I actually fetched the data from rtdb by app directely and iterating and creating json data but really thanks for answering .

Comment: Could you also look at this question if possible ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71093131/why-data-variables-are-persisting-the-old-values-in-flutter-app/71096766?noredirect=1#comment125685284_71096766